# error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject' while installing fyers-apiv3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to install fyers-apiv3. but it is giving following error

```
     Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [110 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\base_protocol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_proto.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_reqrep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_ws.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\connector.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\cookiejar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\formdata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\hdrs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_websocket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_writer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\locks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\multipart.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\payload.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\payload_streamer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\pytest_plugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\resolver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\streams.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\tcp_helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\tracing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\typedefs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_app.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_fileresponse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_middlewares.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_protocol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_request.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_response.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_routedef.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_server.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_ws.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\worker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      running egg_info
      writing aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying aiohttp\_cparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_find_header.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_headers.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_helpers.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_helpers.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_http_parser.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_http_writer.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_websocket.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_cparser.pxd.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_find_header.pxd.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_helpers.pyi.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_helpers.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_http_parser.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_http_writer.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_websocket.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\hdrs.py.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp\.hash
      running build_ext
      building 'aiohttp._websocket' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\aiohttp
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Alpha Derivatives\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include" "-IC:\Users\Alpha Derivatives\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.18362.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.18362.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.18362.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.18362.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcaiohttp/_websocket.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\aiohttp/_websocket.obj
      _websocket.c
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(1475): warning C4996: 'Py_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Alpha Derivatives\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3097): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Alpha Derivatives\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3238): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Alpha Derivatives\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3293): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Alpha Derivatives\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3744): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Alpha Derivatives\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.39.33519\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried many things but nothing seems to work. I tried installing the beta version of aiohttps

```
        `$ pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0`
```

this did not work.
Then I installed pyenv and changed the python version to 3.11.6, still getting the same error.

```
        `$pyenv install 3.11.6`
        `$pyenv global 3.11.6`
```

does anyone knows what to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it from scratch.

**Install python 3.11 and create a virtual environment.**

then install `fyers-api-v3`

Comment: I believe these two statements do that. am i missing something? 
       
 `$pyenv install 3.11.6`
        `$pyenv global 3.11.6`